# Change controller and action in class module

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

How to change controller and action in class Module in file Module.php? It is necessary to restrict access without a redirect. The URI should remain unchanged. Thus it is necessary to override not just the template output, namely controller and action.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is to change the matched route handler. You could do something like this:

```php
<?php
/* module/Application/src/Module.php */

namespace Application;

use Application\Controller\IndexController;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Router\Http\RouteMatch;

class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
    {
        if (!$e instanceof MvcEvent) {
            return;
        }

        $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $em->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, [$this, 'preCheck'], 1000);
    }

    public function preCheck(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $e->setRouteMatch(new RouteMatch([
            'controller' => IndexController::class,
            'action' => 'test'
        ]));
    }
}
```

In the onBoostrap Method you register an event handler for the dispatch event. This event is triggered before the controller action gets executed. In your event handler you could then overwrite the already matched route. 
With this solution you stay on the same route but another controller can handle the request.